# facebook login auto wall post and database insert using php mysql

Tags: php, facebook

I need a login system using facebook, here are some requirements i need as facebook login, auto wall post when login first time at my site. need to insert user name, email, facebookid, access token to mysql. i have created facebook app when i testing with this code facebook login working and redirecting to my page but no wall post and no database inserting.

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');
require_once 'facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'     => '##########',
    'secret'    => '#######################',
    'cookie'    => true
));


$user = $facebook->getUser();
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();        
if($user)
{
$udata = $facebook->api($user);
$facebook_id=$udata['id'];
$name=$u['name'];
$email=$u['email'];
$gender=$u['gender'];

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM facebookusers WHERE facebook_id = '$facebook_id' ");
$count=mysql_num_rows($query);

if($count == 0)
{
$ins = "INSERT INTO `facebookusers` (`facebook_id`, `name`, `email`, `gender`, `access_token`) 
VALUES ('$facebook_id', '$name', '$email', '$gender', '$access_token')";
$result = mysql_query($ins) or die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());

$news = array(
            'access_token'  => '$access_token',
            'message'       => 'Test Message',
            'name'          => 'Facebook Application Test Link',
            'link'          => 'mydomain.com',
            'caption'       => 'Test Caption',
            'description'   => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.',
            'picture'       => './picture.png'
        );

        $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST', $news);
}       
        ?>
<?php
}
else
{

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array( 'req_perms' => 'email,user_birthday,status_update,offline_access'));
echo '<a href="'.$loginUrl.'"><img src="facebook.png" title="Login with Facebook" /></a>';

}

?>
```

Comment: Can you paste your php error log?

Answer (score 0):

The access token changes each time the user uses your website or Facebook application and so you shouldn't be storing it, I should also mention that most users won't be too willing to grant offline access to their account and news feed

You need to use scope to access extended permissions `$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array( 'scope' => 'read_stream,etc'));`
And be sure to request the permissions as defined here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-permissions/

As I said, ask for the bare minimum because you may put users off your app and make them less likely to give you their information, they will have to confirm access on first login.

Finally try taking the quotes off the column names in your query

```
$ins = "INSERT INTO `facebookusers` (facebook_id,name,email,gender) VALUES ('$facebook_id', '$name', '$email', '$gender')";
```

Hope that helps mate